# phpldapadmin not loading php

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ldap, ubuntu-16.04

For some reason my phpldapadmin doesn't want to work with my website and it says "If you are seeing this in your browser, PHP is not installed on your web server!!!" Which is not true as if the info.php file is navigated to like here it says php is enabled along with the ldap extension. The apache error log doesn't say anything about the error though.

Every other php page on my website works except phpldapadmin. I am really confused.

This is what I get when I run php -v

```
PHP 7.1.1-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2017 09:20:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.1-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Please add related Apache configuration and log files to your question.

Comment: This is what confuses me, there are no errors in the log file

Comment: Yesterday you said _no_ PHP pages were working. But now you say they are working, except for this one. But you didn't post an answer to the other question. What is really going on here?

Comment: Can you please run php -v on the server directly ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I have no idea myself to be honest

Comment: @Tolsadus, I have updated the post

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without seeing Apache configuration.